# How do I start a daemon on startup with SysV init?

Tags: linux, boot, daemon, sysvinit

I use MX Linux, which uses SysV init.
Some softwares (like mullvad-vpn in my case) made for SystemD have their daemons not launching on startup. I can launch it with `sudo service mullvad-daemon start` but I can't find how to have it to be automatically launched on startup. It's possible to launch MX Linux with SystemD and the process does automatically start in that case.
The file `/etc/rc2.d/K01mullvad-daemon` exists, do I have to make any changes to it ? How do I have it to automatically start when using SysV ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How about this? $ sudo update-rc.d mullvad-daemon defaults